# How to get the billing address from Klrana widget?

Tags: javascript, klarna

In the Klanra widget,is it possible to get a saved billing address?
I cannot find this in the Klrana docs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbaOs.jpg)

Is it possible or not?

How to get a billing address from widget?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.